# how to create excel sheet without return ModelAndView?

Tags: java, spring, excel, spring-mvc

hi am create excel sheet using extends AbstractExcelView i write following code

```
public ModelAndView exportToExcel(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, ? extends Object> params, ShipmentDetailsSearchInput shipmentDetailsInputType) throws ParseException
    {

        Map<String, Object> excelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return new ModelAndView("ExcelReport", UIErrorMessages.DATA, excelMap);
    }
```

i wont to get Ajax response that file download success in Extjs Ajax response because ModelAndView Not Give any response in submit ajax call.

how to we can write restful excel-download component  without modeandview in spring 3

Comment: Your question is not all clear to me. But you could pass `HttpServletResponse` as parameter and writes the Excel file on the output stream directly. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: no i create dynamic excel file using AbstractExcelView

Comment: OK, but you can use Apache POI to directly write the Excel file on a given OutputStream.

Comment: you have good link about its then share with me.

Comment: Apache POI -> http://poi.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dynamic excel file sheet then you can use Apache POI. You can create ,update and modify excel sheet.

Comment: in that case i wont to download both file and get status on one AJAX call that i not able to get

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache POI to generate an excel file and filling it.
More details can be found [here](http://poi.apache.org/), [example link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractexcelview/) and another [example link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/).

Please note you don't have to use Ajax and can directly map a GET request to the method `exportToExcel`.

To avoid return ModelAndView object, you can directly write the generated file into response stream.
You will have to set `ContentType` and `HttpServletResponse` header to appropriate format,
 as show below:

```
public void exportToExcel(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, ? extends Object> params, ShipmentDetailsSearchInput shipmentDetailsInputType, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws ParseException
    {

 //  Map<String, Object> excelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 //  return new ModelAndView("ExcelReport", UIErrorMessages.DATA, excelMap);
      String fileName = "RandomFile";
      HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
      header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "vnd.ms-excel"));
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
//method to create Workbook
      Workbook book = createFileAndFillDetails();

       try {
        book.write(response.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: hi but i wont to return message in Ajax response in void message return not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use Ajax there are no direct solutions. The choices you are left with are :

1) Using a hidden frame as mentioned in [How to download file from server using jQuery AJAX and Spring MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722716/how-to-download-file-from-server-using-jquery-ajax-and-spring-mvc-3)

2) Redirect the browser

3) Don't use ajax at all, because ajax/jquery is not going to be useful to handle this scenario. A url with GET request offers easy approach as mentioned in the other solution proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand correctly your question, you want to create an excel spreadsheet when an asynchronous call is made to your controller (so via AJAX).

First of all, I don't think it's a good idea to download file via ajax call. If your problem is a long time to generate your excel spreadsheet, I suggest you to generate it asynchronously (in a separate thread for example) and than to download the generated file via a classical GET request.

I'm doing something similar in a web application that generate a large CSV file. I'm using this simple method to get the generated file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(
        @RequestParam(value = "token", required = false) String token,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // my logic...

        String formattedDataString = exportTask.getResults());

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                + exportTask.getExportFileName() + "\"");
        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        IOUtils.copy(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(formattedDataString.getBytes()),
                response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

In my page I have a simple link like this:

```
<c:url var="fileUrl" value="results/file">
        <c:param name="token" value="${token}" />
    </c:url>
<a href='<c:out value="${fileUrl}" />'>Get File</a>
```

In my case the `token` param identify the generated file, that is stored in the local DB.

However, if you still want to use ajax, I suggest you to take a look to [`@ResponseBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) annotation.