# How to let user download a file in ajax success method?

Tags: java, javascript, file, spring-mvc

I'm trying to let user download a file from server.
I use ServletOutputStream in my controller (here is the code)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-backup-file", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getBackupFile(
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    File backupFile = new File("PATH_TO_FILE");        

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setContentLength((int)backupFile.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "database backup" + "\"");

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(backupFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    int length;
    while( (length = in.read(buffer) ) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush();        
}
```

My client side looks like this:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: 'URL_TOCONTROLLER_METHOD',
        contentType: "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {   
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

when I console.log the data it has the content of the file, but I want this file to be downloaded tu the user, not just printed. how can make let user to save the data as file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722716/how-to-download-file-from-server-using-jquery-ajax-and-spring-mvc-3

Answer (score 3):

You have to send path where the file stored and open its on success function,then user can download it

if success is like that

```
{"status":"success","path":"temp\/Vehicle_Units_2013_11_04.xls"}
```

script is

```
success: function(msg)
                  {
                      if(msg.status=="session-expired")
                      {
                      window.location.replace("index.jsp");
                      }
                      if(msg.status=="success")
                      {
                          window.open(msg.path);
                      }

                  }
```

Comment: do you mean the path to file? I don't have the url to that file. I'm not understanding this ServletOutputStream staff, what does that do? should I somehow get url of the ServletOutputStream? My main problem is that I don't know how to generate url to that file

Comment: in your server folder path wil be the url.if you dont hav url means how the user will download the file from server?

Comment: then how user will download?

Comment: the file is in server machine but not in the server folder. it's in server's local resource.

Comment: give the path on success thats all:-) we need path to download or else not

Answer (score -1):

You cannot force a file download with Ajax. Javascript cannot save files to the user's computer for a number of security reasons. The solution is to make a controller which serves the download page and have your `success` function change the `window.location` to it.

```
success : function (data) {
    window.location = data;
}
```

assuming `data` is just the URL. You can make this more robust to use JSON or any other response format from which you can retrieve the link.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use ajax. Instead provide a download link.

```
<a href="URL_TOCONTROLLER_METHOD" download>Click To Download</a>
```