# Code to check when page has finished loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, window, pageload

How can I check whether the page has finished loading? When it has, how can I execute a method already created in the C# code behind for that page?

I would like to orchestrate the following sequence of events

1. Finish Loading the page
2. Download a gridview as an Excel file in the page
3. Call this method `download()`
4. Close the browser

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just to confirm you want to have a popup window with an xls download pretty much?

Comment: i want a pop up window where after that page is loaded. i want it to autodowload the xls file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) answer your question?

Example usage (in your C# code)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Page.LoadComplete +=new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}

void  Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call your download function
}
```

Comment: i think so. but i dont know how to use that . confused

Comment: thanks for the code.
Looks like now there is something wrong with my code, as it still no data inside the downloaded data. (nvr show the nested gridview data)

Comment: which is kinda weird though. i thought it should be 'okay' once the page has fully loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry that will have to be another question.  I've never done anything with Excel :(

Comment: You don't need to add an event listener to Page.LoadComplete. Just like Page_Load event, it is being fired by the core. You just need to create the proper method with void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) { //do something }

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery and make a callback to open the xls file.

There is a few solutions detailed here [POST to server, receive PDF, deliver to user w/ jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery)

Basically you can hook into the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // do window.location or another one of the options to download the file.
});
```

Comment: im quite confused with jquery tho. so yea, its kind of difficult for me without a same scenario code. T.T

Comment: seems like this is the way as it must be executed client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in DOM javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
   download()
 }
```