# javascript check before download a file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, proxy, download

I've a need that I didn't think to be so weird, but seeking for answer on web I realized it's a bit complicated.

I have a page with a list of documents to download, let's call it `index.html`. Once a user click on a "download button", a form appears and the user's gonna be requested to provide its email. I have a proxy server file, let's name it `proxy.php`, which receive an *email* and a *document id*, does some things (store the email, read document in a buffer and then provide a http-response with it) and then response with a server status and, eventually, a content.

If I use a html-form to do this, it works perfectly when nothing is wrong, but I can't intercept any exception in case of error
Instead, if I use an ajax request, I can manage status codes, but I find my self with my document stored in a javascript variable and I don't know how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: this answer sounds good but I didn't really undertand how to implement it

Comment: OT: @Rinzler I work as a developer, not as a social-network star ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looking at this thread here: [POST to server, receive PDF, deliver to user w/ jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery)

Assuming your document is pdf-based (though other types should be fine), you can try what the accepted answer has provided:

> On the server side, add the HTTP header:
>
> > > Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whatever.pdf"

Comment: nice, I accepted this answer as it's the most resonable one I found. Anyway, it seems there's no way to do both checking and downloading with a single http call. Thanks