# How can i open a pdf in a popup window with an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf

So I need to be able to open a pdf that is generated, by a server-side script, based on the html that I send it. The html is a huge string. I was thinking using ajax with `widow.open` but I can't seem to wrap my head around how.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pdf",
        data: {input:html},
        success: function(msg) {
            window.open(msg)
        },
        error: function(msg) {

        }
    });
```

I thought this would work, but it did not.

Comment: Would this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2186623/723057 ?

Comment: I believe it what I'm looking for. I can't really comprehend it.

Comment: Do you need help with the JavaScript or the back-end processing? The reason I ask is because I think JavaScript itself cannot generate a PDF, but if can get it from a script and render the right content headers.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a simple cross-browser way. Why not open an `iframe` with the PDF in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST to server, receive PDF, deliver to user w/ jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery)

Comment: So the back end server takes html that I give it and generates a PDF. That PDF is then returned back to me. Sorry if it was initially confusing I been working on this project for 12 straight hours.

Comment: So I discovered that it was better not to do this with ajax. I did it using this tutorial which worked out perfectly. http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/

Answer (score -1):

You can use a jQuery PDF Viewer plugin. For example, using [jsPDF](http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf) you'll write something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "/pdf",
   data : {
      input : html
   },
   success : function (msg) {
      var pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.text(20, 20, msg);
      pdf.output('datauri');
   },
   error : function (msg) {}
});
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it's asking how to view a PDF retrieved from the server with AJAX; not generate a PDF based on content received with AJAX.

Comment: @icktoofay Hmm. Maybe you're right, but looking at code example, I'm not agree with you. It seems to me that the server returns a message (`msg`), not an URL.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but @icktoofay is correct. I need to be able to view the pdf.

Comment: @B7ackAnge7z the msg is actually the returned pdf. I know it confusing.

Comment: @PhongLe In this case an `iframe` can be a solution for your problem. Also, you can use `jsPDF`, but server need to return message, not PDF contents.

Comment: Would be possible to get it into a a different window? The pdf is a report and I really dont want the user to leave the page they were on.