# Download PDF with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Similar to [POST to server, receive PDF, deliver to user w/ jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery) But that doesn't seem to be working here...

I need to POST a request to a server, with a payload of name/value pairs. The server respondes by sending a PDF file

All the user needs to know is that, after clicking a pdf button on the page they get whatever the browser default behavior is (i.e. save or view).

So, the call is a simple one (I think)

```
 $.ajax({
  url:"http://blah.com/etc",
  data:{filename:'output.pdf', foo:'foo', bar:'bar', baz:'baz'},
  type:"POST"
 });
```

That's all the server needs to do its stuff and return output.pdf

It looks like it's working fine. Here are the response headers:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="output.pdf"
Content-Length:17896
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 04:19:06 GMT
Server:nginx
```

And, if I look at the response in Chrome dev tools, it sure looks like a 17k pdf to me...

The last hurdle though is that the browser (Chrome or FF) is doing nothing, I guess I'm missing the bit that says 'now handle this response as a downloadable file'

Comment: you want to get pdf download on a button click? here you can do with HTML5 , all you need to set anchor tag `a` with url of pdf location and add attribute `download`

Comment: Thanks Satinder, but that doesn't deal with the payload data and I still have one or two IE8 users out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time I've answered my own question so, here goes...

There is a JQuery forum post on this subject here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/download-file-from-jquery-post

It appears that the reason this doesn't work and never will is that these headers never reach the browser in a way that the browser can respond to - AJAX results are passed to the calling script without browser intervention.

Makes perfect sense really.

Still interested in case anyone has a better solution but, as of now, I'm generating a hidden form at runtime using JQuery and then firing off a .submit()

That's working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save/open file, you could use php alternatively. See below:

First, make a file name 'download.php' contain the following code:

```
$filename = $_GET['fname']; 
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browsers 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($filename) . '";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));   

readfile($filename);

$fp=fopen($filename,"rb");


if(!feof($fp)){
  print(fread($fp,1024*8));

  flush();
  ob_flush();
  if(connection_aborted){

  }
}else{
 echo 'File has been downloaded.';
}
exit;
```

Then, call your download.php:

```
<a href="download.php?fname=sample.pdf">Sample file</a>
```

This code can be used to download any file type.

P.S. Always be careful with the path and the permission issue.

Hope it's useful...

Cheers,